# Correct way to pass data to showOptionsDialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I'm currently trying to pass data into an AlertDialog from an onItemLongClick method and I'm trying to find the best/correct practice as to how I do this.

Whilst what I'm doing at the moment works, it feels wrong and I'm hoping someone here will be able to provide me with the correct solution and an explanation as to why it is the correct solution.

My code is as follows and at the moment within the long onItemLongClick I'm setting a property to the row item within the list view which has been clicked, then accessing that property from within the a AlertDialog.Builder.

```
public class ListViewExample {

    private long clickedRowId;
    ....

    mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new ListView.OnItemLongClickListener () {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long rowId) {
            clickedRowId = rowId;
            /* here is my issue, surely it is better to pass rowId into showOptionsDialog as an argument? */
            showOptionsDialog();
            return true;
        }
    });


    private void showOptionsDialog() {

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this.context)
            .setTitle(R.string.stack_dialog_title)
            .setItems(R.array.stack_options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int selected) {

                    switch (selected) {
                    case 0:
                        //perform selection #1
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        //perform selection #2
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        deleteRowItem(clickedRowId);
                        break;
                    }

                }

        }).show();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ListViewExample {

....

mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new ListView.OnItemLongClickListener () {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long rowId) {
        /* here is my issue, surely it is better to pass rowId into showOptionsDialog as an argument? */
        showOptionsDialog(rowId);
        return true;
    }
});


private void showOptionsDialog(long rowId) {
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);
   builder.setTitle(R.string.stack_dialog_title);
   builder.setItems(R.array.stack_options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int selected) {
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        switch (selected) {
            case 0:
                //perform selection #1
                break;
            case 1:
                //perform selection #2
                break;
            case 2:
                deleteRowItem(rowId);
                break;
            }
         }
     });
      AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
       alert.show():


     }


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think u can do it like this. hope it can help u

public class ListViewExample {

```
    private long clickedRowId;
    ....

    mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new ListView.OnItemLongClickListener () {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<YourObj> list, View arg1, int position, long rowId) {
            clickedRowId = rowId;
            YourObj clickObj list.getItemAtPosition(position)
            /* here is my issue, surely it is better to pass rowId into showOptionsDialog as an argument? */

            showOptionsDialog(clickObj );
            return true;
        }
    });


    private void showOptionsDialog(YourObj clickedObj) {

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this.context)
            .setTitle(R.string.stack_dialog_title)
            .setItems(R.array.stack_options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int selected) {

                    switch (selected) {
                    case 0:
                        //perform selection #1
                         //do some thing about clickedObj
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        //perform selection #2
                        //do some thing about clickedObj
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        deleteRowItem(clickedRowId);
                        break;
                    }

                }

        }).show();
    }


}
```